# How to know what is the default audio device? /dev/audio or /dev/dsp in ubuntu?

Tags: linux

I was trying to play random songs command line using mpg123. But did not know what is my default audio device. or if I need to specify any other audio device with the '-a' option. Both /dev/audio and /dev/dsp are audio devices. How to know which one is default ?

Answer (score 3):

The default sound system is [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/) and `/dev/audio` or `/dev/dsp` ([OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System) interfaces, deprecated in Linux) is only an emulation layer over ALSA -- and not even a fully functional one, at that.

The default ALSA device is "`default`", and if you install [mpg123-alsa](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mpg123-alsa), it should Do The Right Thing without requiring any options.

Comment: Note that ALSA devices need not directly correspond to hardware devices (like OSSv3 did), they are much more flexible and can include additional filter chains, route to multiple hardware devices, etc. Usually, the default "default" chain is linked to the first sound card device, cf. also `/proc/asound/cards`, and the device node is usually something like `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p`.